# Exiting out of nested functions

Tags: jquery

I have several elements in a class that have a click event attached to them. This calls a popup box with a link on it. The link makes an AJAX call to store the original element id in a database.

The problem is that if you open up the popup on one element and close it then do the same on another element, it will make two separate AJAX calls. When clicking on the link to hide the popup, I need a way to exit the original function that was called. This way it won't make more than one AJAX call at a time.

Below is a basic example of my problem:

```
$(".ulElement").live('click', function(){
    $('#popup').css('visibility','visible');
    var elementNum = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#popupLink1').click((function () { 
        //make Ajax call and send elementNum
    });
    $('#popopLink2').click((function () {
         $('#popup').css('visibility','hidden');
         //I need to exit the function that was called by ulElement here
    });
```

EDIT: This is my code simplified that I need working. Right now, it will still turn every element grey that I've clicked on.

```
$(".position").live('click', function(event){
    $('#seatmenu').css('visibility','visible');
    var seatnum = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $('.stand').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $(".menuhead").click(function(){
        clearMenu();               //this just hides the menu
        event.preventDefault();
    });


    $(".stand").click(function(){
        clearMenu();
        $('#'+seatnum).css('color','grey');
    });
});
```

Comment: Once an AJAX call is in progress, you *can* cancel it, but technically the request has already been made.  You will need to handle the failure of it or end of it separately to another.  Just dismissing the returned information if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

As Orbling said you cannot cancel an AJAX call once it has been made.
If you want to prevent the user from calling the AJAX service multiple times you can simply store a variable to record if the user has clicked it by declaring a global variable. For example

```
var hasUserClickedPopup = false;

$(".ulElement").live('click', function(){
    $('#popup').css('visibility','visible');
    var elementNum = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#popupLink1').click((function () { 
        if(!hasUserClickedPopup )
         {
           //make Ajax call and send elementNum
           hasUserClickedPopup  = true;
          }
    });
    $('#popopLink2').click((function () {
         $('#popup').css('visibility','hidden');
         //I need to exit the function that was called by ulElement here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN actually abort an existing XHR call.

Simply store the `$.ajax` call inside a variable, which can be declared at the top. You can then cancel it before making another request.

**i.e.**

```
var xhr;
$('.button1").click(function() {
    if(xhr == null) {
        xhr = $.ajax(...);
    }
    else {
        xhr.abort();
    }

});

$(".button2").click(function() {
    if(xhr == null) {
        xhr = $.ajax(...);
    }
    else {
        xhr.abort();
    }
});
```